# Vba loop range specific range

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am designing a macro where by when it runs  it looks for a value "2" in column C, and copies that row from cell A-C ONLY, into sheet2. The code I am working is not working. Please could you help me.

```
Sub LoopRange()

  Dim rCell As Range
  Dim rRng As Range

  Set rRng = Sheet1.Range("C1:C20")

  For Each rCell In rRng.Cells

    If rCell.Value = "2" Then
    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(3, 3)).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1)
    End If

  Next rCell

End Sub
```

Comment: When it runs it not picking anything or looping . But tested this With Sheets("Sheet1")

    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(3, 3)).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1)
   End With   "the copying from sheet 1 & pasting to sheet 2 works. But when i try make it loop through the sheet i get no result

Comment: Your copying the exact same range to the exact same location.  I'm guessing this is what you want inside your if statement: `Range(Cells(rCell.Row, 1), Cells(rCell.Row, 3)).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(rCell.Row, 1)`

Comment: Thanks Runner, but i tried that code, was  unsuccessful, cells(1,1),cell(3,3) was my defined range to be copied if the value 2 is found in column C.

Comment: Thanks runner the code you posted worked thanks alot , it seems like cant see it on the time line anymore .

Comment: I had removed it because I miss understood your requirement of copying the same defined range.  I reposted it since it helped you.  Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code is copying the exact same cells to the exact same location every time. Try this instead:

```
Sub test()
  Dim rCell As Range
  Dim rRng As Range
  Dim cnt As Long
  cnt = 1

  Set rRng = Sheet1.Range("C1:C20")

  For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
    If rCell.Value = "2" Then
        Range(Cells(rCell.Row, 1), Cells(rCell.Row, 3)).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(cnt, 1)
        cnt = cnt + 1
    End If
  Next rCell
End Sub
```

Sheet 1 test data:

[image]

Sheet 2 results:

[image]